# drawBox in opengl how to do it use opengl-es?

Tags: opengl-es

I have a function:

```
void drawBox(vector3 a,vector3 b)
{
       glBegin(GL_LINES);
       ...
       glVertex3f(a[0],a[1],a[2]);
       ...
       glEnd(GL_LINES);
}
```

Now I need to do it in opengl-es which need to  use vertex pointer right? but the position of vector a and vector b, changes a lot,such as if it represent as  a bounding box, I've searched this page http://maniacdev.com/2009/05/porting-opengl-glvertex-code-to-iphone-opengl-es/ , it uses a const GLfloat which is not what I need right now,so my question is how to write this function in opengl-es way?

Comment: You already have your data in arrays. Why don't you just set those into the glVertexPointer? It would help to get some actual code of yours so that I we could put it into context.

Comment: Which OpenGL ES? ES 1.1 or ES 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, a);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, number_of_verts);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```